# Python: Optional parameter default dependent on passed argument value

Tags: python, recursion

I've written this simple function that tests whether a given number `n` is prime or not using recursion:

```
def is_prime2(n, div):
    """Recursive primality test"""
    while div >= 2:
        if n % div == 0:
            print 'No, {number} is not prime.'.format(number = n, div = div)
            return False
        else:
            return is_prime2(n, div-1)
    else:
        print 'Yes, {number} is prime indeed.'.format(number = n)
        return 'True'

is_prime2(4,3)
is_prime2(5,4)
is_prime2(6,5)
```

It works, but the `div` parameter I included is bothering me. It is only there for the recursive step, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove it without having to change the entire function. I'd prefer if the function only had one parameter: the number being tested.

I imagine there is a simple way of doing it: could you point me in the right direction please?

Thank you.

Comment: Please, fix your code identation - note that program code should be quoted with the "code" button in the editor.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with just one parameter. Knowing the primeness of every number smaller than N doesn't tell you anything about the primeness of N. In any case, I don't think recursion is a good design choice here anyway. Python has a default maximum recursion depth of about 999, so your script will crash if you try to check the primeness of 1009.

Comment: The only effect recursion has here is to simulate a loop. Just use a loop; Python isn't Lisp or Haskell.

Comment: Hi all, this was more about seeing if it could be done, rather than finding the optimal implementation. I really thought there was an easy way of doing this that I was missing...

Comment: @Baalinooo Python does not make recursion easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can use a default parameter to achieve your goal:

```
def is_prime2(n, div = None):
    """Recursive primality test"""
    if div is None:
        div = n - 1
    while div >= 2:
        if n % div == 0:
            print 'No, {number} is not prime.'.format(number = n, div = div)
            return False
        else:
            return is_prime2(n, div-1)
    else:
        print 'Yes, {number} is prime indeed.'.format(number = n)
        return 'True'

is_prime2(4)
is_prime2(5)
is_prime2(6)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking along those lines (with a try: div except NameError: div = n -1) but couldn't get it to work.